# Spring batch - issue with explicitly setting the job as failed

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to set the status of job as failed in afterJob listener based on few conditions. But the job commits the changes and exits by marking job completed. Below is how I am setting the status. What could be wrong here?

```
        jobExecution.addFailureException(e);
        jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED", "Incorrect data"));
        jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
```

Version: Spring Boot 2.7.0

```
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    String message = "Completed  job.";

    try {
        //get context and batch
        ExecutionContext executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        //processing done here
    } catch (Exception coe) {
        jobExecution.addFailureException(coe);
        jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED", "Could not complete job"));
        jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
        message = jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription();
    } finally {
        try {
            //Database update here. When this fails, the Job is expected be marked FAILED, but its marked COMPLETED
            throw new Exception("DB update failed"); //simulating exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while saving final details to DB. This is printed");
            jobExecution.addFailureException(e);
            jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED", "Could not complete job"));
            jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The status update in the job repository is done after the listener is called, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d444a8abaff05d74c2ad895683e90f8fe5109d38/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/AbstractJob.java#L368-L375. So what you are describing should not happen. Please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine for the response. I tested with the afterJob code I added above now, and it's behaving as expected. Its probably something else causing the issue I am facing. On to more debugging...